# How to implement Ueff​=U−J in a Quantum ESPRESSO input file?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, physical-properties-of-materials, software-input-file-request, hubbard-model

I want to implement Ueff​=U−J in a Quantum ESPRESSO input file, but I don't know how to do that.

I found the following on the internet:

```
lda_plus_u = .TRUE.

lda_plus_u_kind = 1
Hubbard_u(i) = U
Hubbard_J(k, i) = J_{ki}
```

I will replace U by a value that I'll extract from the literature, **but I don't know what I should replace k and J with, or what their meaning is.**

Comment: $J$ is the Hund coupling  constant, which also may be found in the literature. See this article for more information: https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.04213

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if there's any update you can give us after all these months? Also, are you still actively in need of an answer to this question? Was the comment by @Sha helpful?